# How to extract Json data from Zip file and to send the extracted Json file to front-end?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I have downloaded zip file containing `json` file and i extracted  the files in the back-end (we are on java environment). My next step is to send the extracted `json` file to front-end (**Angular 7**).

```
String zipName = "facebook-srikanthmukku.zip";

    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipName);
         ZipInputStream zis =
             new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis))) {

        ZipEntry entry;

        // Read each entry from the ZipInputStream until no
        // more entry found indicated by a null return value
        // of the getNextEntry() method.
        while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Unzipping: " + entry.getName());

            int size;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

            try (FileOutputStream fos =
                     new FileOutputStream(entry.getName());
                 BufferedOutputStream bos =
                     new BufferedOutputStream(fos, buffer.length)) {

                while ((size = zis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                    bos.write(buffer, 0, size);
                }
                bos.flush();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java you can read .json file like the following and convert it into JSONObject

```
JSONObject readObject = new JSONObject( (IOUtils.toString( new FileInputStream( filePath ),  StandardCharsets.UTF_8) ))
```

If you are using Spring Rest, in the controller you can do like this

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "jsonfile", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public String returnJson()
{

    JSONObject readObject = new JSONObject( (IOUtils.toString( new FileInputStream( filePath ),  StandardCharsets.UTF_8) ))

     return readObject.toString();
}
```

Then you can consume in the angular application by creating a service with get method to the above specified URL.

Your angular service should look like the following if you have started your java spring application in localhost and port 8080

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of, observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';    

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class jsonService{

constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

public getJsonFiles(): Observable<any[]>{
 return this.httpClient.get<any>('http:/localhost:8080/jsonfile')
}
}
```

Comment: Hi venkat,Thanks for your reply.but it showing error.I have imported